# How to run a command/program using system account in Linux

Tags: permissions, ldap, kerberos

My goal is to run LDAP search and get a password for a gMSA account.

- I have an Ubuntu VM which is `Dev_Linux`.
- My user account is `sja`.
- I want to run LDAP search using the `Dev_Linux` account. I refer to this account as system account or machine account.

When my account `sja` is added as allowed principals, I am able to retrieve the password. My my expected setup is that the machine account is added to a host group that is in allowed principals. Thus if I am able to run the ldap search with machine account, I should be able to retrieve the password.

I ran the `kinit` and `klist -k` which shows that the machine account has the permission.

But I am stuck at how to run LDAP search as machine account, in this case as `Dev_Linux` but not as `sja` or `root`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Is it clear?
Also appreciate if you know how to resolve my issue.
Thank you !

Comment: I'm hoping it's clearer for someone who knows about LDAP and Kerberos than I do.

Comment: Are you looking for `sudo -u Dev_Linux ldapsearch`?

Comment: No,
It did not work 
"sudo: unknown user  Dev_Linux"

as per my understanding, this machine account is not user account. (type is different)
any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The *machine account* is essentially a Kerberos/AD account. Unlike Windows, Linux doesn't have built-in OS concept for machine accounts.

But a *machine account* is essentially a set of network authentication credentials that is usable for every user on the local system.

Disclaimer: The following is based on my old notes. I don't currently have a working Kerberos environment I could use to test with.

You could (together with your Kerberos/AD administrator, if necessary) create a Kerberos keytab file for the machine account:

```
ktutil -v -k /some/where/Dev_Linux.keytab add -p Dev_Linux@SOME_REALM
```

Then place the keytab to a location accessible to all users on your local system.

(If your Kerberos service is actually Active Directory, and your system uses AD-integrated authentication, your system probably already has something that maintains such a keytab on your local system for the machine account, and periodically updates the machine account password and the keytab file if necessary to satisfy AD security requirements. If so, it might be just a matter of finding the keytab file and arranging for suitable permissions for users to read it. The location of such a keytab file might vary depending on how your AD integration is implemented.)

To authenticate using machine authentication, you would set a custom credential cache name (to avoid interference with your personal Kerberos account), and use the keytab to authenticate using the machine account.

For example:

```
kinit -c /tmp/krb5cc_machine --keytab=/some/where/Dev_Linux.keytab Dev_Linux@SOME_REALM
```

Because the machine account password is encrypted within the keytab, this command can be executed non-interactively. You would run this e.g. at the start of your login session, or perhaps at suitable intervals to renew the cached authentication tickets, as they will eventually expire.

To use the cached machine account credential, set the `KRB5CCNAME` environment variable to point to the credential cache that was `kinit`ed with the machine account keytab, and unset it (or restore it to existing value) when wishing to authenticate as your personal account.

So, after these preparations, to run a `ldapsearch` using the machine account:

```
KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/krb5cc_machine ldapsearch -U Dev_Linux <necessary options and parameters...>
```

You'll probably need to include an option for `ldapsearch` to specify that you want to use `Dev_Linux` instead of your current local username. I believe the necessary option for it would be `-U Dev_Linux`.

It might even be enough to just set the environment variable `KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` to point to the machine account keytab file, and supply the machine account username to the LDAP search tool. If the Kerberos support in the LDAP search tool is smart enough, it might automatically fetch the necessary authentication tickets... but you might still need to set a non-conflicting KRB5CCNAME to not mix your personal account authentication tickets with the machine account ones, so that you can control whether you use the machine account or your personal one for a specific task.

So, after you've verified that the LDAP search using the machine account works after an explicit `kinit` using the keytab file, you can try it without the `kinit`:

```
kdestroy -c /tmp/krb5cc_machine 
KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME=FILE:/some/where/Dev_Linux.keytab KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/krb5cc_machine ldapsearch -U Dev_Linux <options and parameters...>
```

If successful, then the only things you need for using the machine account are access to the keytab file and,two environment variable assignments (`KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` and `KRB5CCNAME`) and the option to use the correct username for the machine account.